# Login with twitter with fabric framework

Tags: android, twitter

I want to login to my android app with Twitter login. For this 
1)I create key and API key from twitter developer console
2)Install plugin Fabric

But Fabric framework does not show twitter kit

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Due to Google's acquisition of Fabric from Twitter, Twitter decided to no longer over their SDK through Fabric. If you want to install Twitter, you should install it via the steps mentioned here: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/overview

Comment: I try but not success. Have you any videos, sample code.

Comment: Twitter Kit is no longer available via Fabric so there is not any code to provide. The site I linked to has the details for installing Twitter Kit in your app.